# Another inequality with exponential sum and trigonometry

Tags: derivatives, trigonometry, inequality, power-series, exponentiation

Playing with $\tan$ and $\sin$ I get :

> > Let $a,b>0$ such that $a+b=1$ then we have :
> >     $$\Big(\sin\Big(\frac{a\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)^{2\tan\Big(\frac{b\pi}{2}\Big)}+\Big(\sin\Big(\frac{b\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)^{2\tan\Big(\frac{a\pi}{2}\Big)}\leq 1$$

I try to exploit the [derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derivative%20sin%28x*pi%2F2%29%5E%282*tan%28%281-x%29*pi%2F2%29%29%2Bsin%28%281-x%29*pi%2F2%29%5E%282*tan%28%28x%29*pi%2F2%29%29%20) and use the closed interval method .
Much harder I try to, use [power series](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series%20sin%28x*pi%2F2%29%5E%282*tan%28%281-x%29*pi%2F2%29%29%2Bsin%28%281-x%29*pi%2F2%29%5E%282*tan%28%28x%29*pi%2F2%29%29%20at%20x%3D0.5) at $x=0.5$

Another way will be to divide the problem in two as:

$$\Big(\sin\Big(\frac{x\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)^{2\tan\Big(\frac{(1-x)\pi}{2}\Big)}\leq 0.5+\alpha(0.5x-x^2)+\beta(0.5-x)$$

And

$$\Big(\sin\Big(\frac{(1-x)\pi}{2}\Big)\Big)^{2\tan\Big(\frac{(x)\pi}{2}\Big)}\leq 0.5-\alpha(0.5^2-x0.5)-\beta(0.5-x)$$
 I can find the right constants but I can't prove it .

Finally I think we can do something with the Bernoulli's inequality .

The equality case is : $a=b=0.5$ and $a=0$ or $a=1$

Thanks a lot for your comment and answer .

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

Due to symmetry, assume that $a \ge b$.
By using $a = 1- b$ and $b\in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$, the desired inequality is written as
$$(\sin \tfrac{(1-b)\pi}{2})^{2\tan \frac{b\pi}{2}}
+ (\sin \tfrac{b\pi}{2})^{2\tan \frac{(1-b)\pi}{2}} \le 1.$$

Let us first prove the case when $b\in (0, \frac{1}{3}]$.

We give the following auxiliary results (Facts 1 through 5). Their proof is not difficult and hence omitted.

*Fact 1*: $1 - \frac{7}{6} b^2 \ge \sin \frac{(1-b)\pi}{2}$ for $b\in (0, \frac{1}{3}]$.

*Fact 2*: $\tan \frac{b\pi}{2} \ge \frac{b\pi}{2} \ge \frac{3}{2}b$ for $b \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$.

*Fact 3*: $\sin \frac{b\pi}{2} \le \frac{b\pi}{2} \le \frac{11}{7}b$ for $b \in (0, \frac{1}{2}]$.

*Fact 4*: $\tan \frac{(1-b)\pi}{2} \ge \frac{19}{5}-\frac{25}{4}b$ for $b \in (0, \frac{1}{3}]$.

*Fact 5*: $(1-x)^r \le 1 - rx$ for $r \in (0, 1]$ and $0 < x < 1$.

From Facts 1, 2 and 5, we have
$$(\sin \tfrac{(1-b)\pi}{2})^{2\tan \frac{b\pi}{2}} 
\le (1 - \tfrac{7}{6}b^2)^{2\tan \frac{b\pi}{2}}
\le (1 - \tfrac{7}{6}b^2)^{3b}
\le 1 - \tfrac{7}{2}b^3.$$
From Facts 3 and 4, we have
$$(\sin \tfrac{b\pi}{2})^{2\tan \frac{(1-b)\pi}{2}} 
\le (\tfrac{11}{7}b)^{2\tan \frac{(1-b)\pi}{2}}
\le (\tfrac{11}{7}b)^{38/5 - 25b/2}.$$

It suffices to prove that for $b\in (0, \frac{1}{3}]$, 
$$1 - \tfrac{7}{2}b^3 + (\tfrac{11}{7}b)^{38/5 - 25b/2} \le 1.$$
It is not difficult with computer. Omitted.

Comment: I have a question: why it's more difficult on the part $b\in[\frac{1}{3},0.5]$?Or it's just a problem of tools ?Furthermore with my other way I think I can achieve the proof .But let me the time for that. Thanks (+1)

Comment: @The.old.boy  The equality occurs at $b=0$ and $b=1/2$. We need bounds for them respectively.  Maybe it is not really more difficult. By using appropriate bounds, one may prove the other part.